# ServiceStack: Self-Host LiveReload not working

Tags: servicestack

I have a self hosted ServiceStack application which I intend to use to develop an angular application with.

The problem is, previously, every time I've made a change to a static file, I've had to restart all the services for it to pick up the changes.

I'm wondering if I'm missing something? I've enabled the `LiveReload` option from `RazorFormat` but it doesnt seem to have done anything? I still have to restart the whole application for it to pick up changes?

I've created a small repro here: https://github.com/CallumVass/ServiceStackSelfHost

If I make changes to the `Default.cshtml` file the changes arent picked up until I restart the service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that he was changing the **source** file and not the **output** file. Since SS copies the files to `/bin/debug` he needed to change that version.

Using [HostConfig settings](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/HostConfig.cs), we were able to to use the `WebHostPhysicalPath` property in the following way during development, while setting up the SS Config:

```cs
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
#if DEBUG
    DebugMode = true,
    WebHostPhysicalPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine("~".MapServerPath(), "..", "..")),
#endif
});
```

This took us out of `/bin/debug` and back to the source.

Comment: To clarify it's VS.NET's that copies output dlls to `/bin` directory. Also the shorter `WebHostPhysicalPath = "~/../../".MapServerPath()"` should also work.

Comment: Eli, I have replaced `@"..\..\"` with `"..",".."` to make it both Windows and Mono compatible.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `AppHost` config to `debug` mode:

```cs
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
    DebugMode = true,
});
```

For performance reasons changes are only monitored for in Debug mode. [See here](http://razor.servicestack.net/) for more information.

> **Automatic reload of modified views, layout templates and partials (in Debug mode)**
>
> The best way to avoid the Start-Up penalty is to avoid having to restart the AppDomain in the first place. So in Debug Mode we'll also do this where a background file system watcher monitors all pages, partials and Layout templates for modifications and recompiles and auto-reloads them on the fly, all-ready to deliever instant response time once the page is requested.

Comment: Just tried that but still need to restart the services for it to pick up changes

Comment: That's very odd. I'll try running your solution and see what happens.

Comment: I just pushed a new version with the DebugMode added

Comment: I've just tried with a V3 app and get the same issue, so it seems to be at least over a year old bug?

Comment: I wonder if its because its looking in the Debug/Release folder? The files in there aren't being changed, its the files in the actual project directory which should be being monitored?

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense, yes you would have to modify the `bin` folder copies, that's the ones it picks up. I forgot that ... I haven't used razor in a long time. So perhaps the solution would be to point ServiceStack to the correct directory such as a directory called `pages` under the project directory. I'll give that a test

Comment: If thats the case, I would have thought that by default when in debug mode etc.. it would be using the files in the project directory anyway, very rarely do you modify the files in the Debug/Release folder directly?