# ServiceStack Razor files in separate project

Tags: architecture, servicestack, servicestack-razor

I have a solution consisting of a ServiceStack back-end, with the regular setup (AppHost, ServiceInterface and ServiceModel), and both a winforms app and a iOS app consuming services.

Now I'd like to make a web-admin, and am **looking for advice on how to structure this**. I'd like to keep the apphost project small, as [SS docs say](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Physical-project-structure)

> Ideally the root-level AppHost project should be kept lightweight and
>   implementation-free.

So I'd like to **have the web-admin in a separate project**, with all the .cshtml and content and it all.

Is this possible? Not recommended? Any ideas?

Some alternatives I can think of are

- single-page-app, let the few `cshtml` files live in the AppHost-project. Is this worth the learning curve?
- have the separate project call the web-services. Wouldn't that be very ineffective, considering that they live on the same web-server? Or should it be considered an advantage, since it makes everything loosely coupled?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the docs on using [Compiled Razor Views](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Compiled-Razor-Views) and the [ServiceStack.Gap](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Gap) GitHub repository on how to create embedded ServiceStack solutions that utilizes Compiled Razor Views.

Comment: Thanks, this got me where I wanted, but there was some initial trouble with the assembly not compiling and errors everywhere. I didn't know that SS.Razor had to be referenced in the new compiled assembly as well, although it's pretty straight forwards, but the VS error messages were off.

Comment: In the docs it says "Retains optimal development workflow". But when I change .cshtml file in the external DLL, it isn't reflected until I stop debugging and recompiles. Anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @specimen self-hosting looks at razor views that are copied to the `/bin` directory after each build. See this answer on how you can change the `Config.WebHostPhysicalPath` to [point to your solution folder instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25849210/85785).

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to provide a more complete answer for beginners:

1. The project for the web-site must be razor enabled. It must have a reference to `ServiceStack.Razor` for example, so the `.cshtml` will compile.
2. As pointed out by @mythz, add the `ServiceStack.Razor.BuildTask` to precompile the razor files. This is necessary to get them included the `LoadFromAssemblies` parameter
3. In the main AppHost, specify that Razor files are to be found in the other assembly with `LoadFromAssemblies` e.g:

   ```
       this.Plugins.Add(new RazorFormat { LoadFromAssemblies = { typeof(ActivityServer.Admin.AdminServices).Assembly } });
   ```
4. So far it's been all about the Razor .cshtml files. To also include services, e.g. for more complex views, just add this to the `AppHost() : base(...)`, or if you want a prefix to those services use AppHost.RegisterService.

One thing to point out is that there is no separate namespace for Razor files in the external DLL, so a "hello.cshtml" in the external DLL collides with a file with the same name in the main AppHost. By putting all cshtml files (in the external dll) under a sub-folder, that will help, because the folder will be part of the URL.