# ServiceStack selfhosting disable caching for memory

Tags: model-view-controller, servicestack

Using Selfhosting standard ServiceStack MVC Application every request get cached in the memory. Changing any js file have no conscience until i restart the server.
Is there any way around this problem for developing purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every request does not get cached in memory, when you're self-hosting it's running the binary dlls and static files that are copied into your `/bin` folder.

You can change `Config.WebHostPhysicalPath` to change ServiceStack to [serve files from your solution folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25849210/85785) instead, e.g:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
#if DEBUG
    DebugMode = true,
    WebHostPhysicalPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine("~".MapServerPath(), "..", "..")),
#endif
});
```